# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ctranslate2

Tags: python, docker, opennmt

I'm learning to use docker and I'm having trouble installing Ctransalte2 inside a docker image. When I run docker build i'm getting the above error.  I'm using python:3.8.12 base image which I suspect is the problem. I know Ctranslate2 will only run on Linux/Mac. Do I need to specificity the OS in the base image?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.12
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that start with a simpler task. But For libraries that are popular and under principled maintenance, you can find the official docker container (with a variety of flavors) on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/opennmt/ctranslate2/tags) and use them.

```
docker pull opennmt/ctranslate2
```

Moreover, if you are in to do it yourself, you can always use official and unofficial GitHub `Dockerfile` samples to follow, like [this one](https://github.com/OpenNMT/CTranslate2/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile)!